# Use same function to expand checkbox select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two select lists with checkboxes and I want to use same function `showCheckboxes` to manage them to avoid code repeating but having problems with selecting the right checkbox list, it doesnt work by id:

```
    <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" id="select1" onclick="showCheckboxes(this.id)">
        <select>
            <option>Select deliverer</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="deliverer_checkboxes" style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
      <% @deliverers.each do |deliverer|  %>
          <label for="<%= deliverer.id %>"><%= check_box_tag "deliverer_user_ids[]", deliverer.id %> <%= deliverer.name %></label>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" id="select2" onclick="showCheckboxes(this.id)">
        <select>
            <option>Select shopper</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="shopper_checkboxes" style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
      <% @shoppers.each do |shopper|  %>
          <label for="<%= shopper.id %>"><%= check_box_tag "shopper_user_ids[]", shopper.id %> <%= shopper.name %></label>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var expanded = false;
  function showCheckboxes(clicked_id) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
      if (!expanded) {
          checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
          expanded = true;
      } else {
          checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
          expanded = false;
      }
  }
</script>

<style>
    .multiselect {
        width: 200px;
        float:left;
    }
    .selectBox {
        position: relative;
    }
    .selectBox select {
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .overSelect {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
    #deliverer_checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
    }
    #deliverer_checkboxes label {
        display: block;
    }
    #deliverer_checkboxes label:hover {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
    }
    #shopper_checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
    }
    #shopper_checkboxes label {
        display: block;
    }
    #shopper_checkboxes label:hover {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you check whether it passes the id correctly? (e.g. by using console)

Comment: after i click twice on my select list it disappears

Comment: That's not what I asked for. Add the statement ´console.log(clicked_id)´ as first statement in your showCheckboxes function. Then load the page and hit F12. See if it passes the value correctly. Report that here.

Comment: yes, its correct id

Answer (score 0):

instead of sharing the expanded variable, check the "expanded" flag directly from the element you clicked. one way is to check the display, since you're toggling it.

```
function showCheckboxes(clicked_id) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    var display = checkboxes.style.display;
    checkboxes.style.display = display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: when i click the checkbox list two times it disappears. same case as with the originl code. chrome.

Comment: and when i click it once nothing happens.

Comment: are you trying to hide/show the `deliverer_checkboxes` and `shopper_checkboxes` ? if that's the case, you can pass `deliverer_checkboxes` and `shopper_checkboxes` to each `showCheckboxes`.

Comment: i want two lists with checkboxes and expand them, not hide

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking to do, but the reason you're getting the behaviour you see is:

1) the "Click twice" - you have set the initial value of `expanded` to false when the boxes are expanded, so you'll need to actually click twice to toggle the hide.  You can correct that by setting it to `true` initially

2) a similar problem exists with re-using the code the way it is. You have one `expanded` variable for multiple `selectBox`. So whichever `selectBox` you pick will store its value in that variable and that value will apply to all other `selectBox`.

You can correct both problems with something like

```
  function showCheckboxes(clicked_id) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementById(clicked_id);

      var expanded = (checkboxes.style.display == 'none') ? false : true;

      if (!expanded) {
          checkboxes.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
          checkboxes.style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/lahulabilo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: it hides the whole select list when clicked twice as well

Comment: I've tested my jsbin above again in FF, Chrome and IE 11 and the select lists each hide for me when clicked once. Looking at the other answer, it seems we're both unclear on what you're looking for exactly. Perhaps you might reword your question to clarify?